# Add URL.Action to javascript method in Razor View

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, url.action

I have a question on how to put my Url Action to razor view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyTypes, false, new {id = "myId", onchange = "onMyTypeChange('Url.Action("GetMyFields", "MyController")')"})
```

Do you have any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: where is the leading `'`? you have an ending `'` after `"MyController")'` but where is the leading one?

Comment: I fixed it, bu it's still now working

Comment: try `'@Url.Action`

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid: Not true. Only reserved keywords need to be prefixed with `@`, such as `@class`, because `class` is a keyword and will be misinterpreted otherwise. `id` is not a keyword, and is fine.

Comment: @ChrisPratt ahh okay, I didn't know that. But his `onchange` needs to be prefixed with `@`, right?

Comment: @ChrisPratt gotcha, also I am looking at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor(v=vs.118).aspx).. what is the `false` in the OP's 2nd parameter? Does that need to be there? I am looking at some of my examples and none of my `EditorFor`'s have a boolean as a 2nd parameter.. I have the expression and then htmlAttributes

Comment: Wait, sorry. Context is everything, and I wasn't paying close enough attention there. Since the string in question is *already* in the context of something Razor is parsing, it needs to be concatenated in, i.e. `onchange = "onMyTypeChange('" + Url.Action(...) + "')"`

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid: Technically, that would be the `templateName` param, but false makes no logical sense in that context. My powers of observation are pitiful this morning, though, as I totally missed the biggest problem here until you pointed that out. For `EditorFor`, the anonymous object is going into `additionalViewData`, *not* `htmlAttributes` like with `TextBoxFor`, for example. If it's MVC 5.1+ you can still pass HTML attributes, but you have to do `new { htmlAttributes = new { ... } }`. In previous versions, though, you need a custom editor template and you have to do it manually.

Comment: @ChrisPratt That was going to be my next suggestion.. as i was looking into my examples I saw that my `EditorFor`'s had `new { htmlAttributes = new { id` and so on and so on..

Comment: @ChrisPratt maybe we both need a bigger cup of coffee :)

Comment: Haha. Yeah. Well, feel free to go ahead and compile this as an answer. You did most of the investigation, and would have gotten there eventually with or without my input.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a couple of problems in your syntax for this line of code.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyTypes, false, new {id = "myId", onchange = "onMyTypeChange('Url.Action("GetMyFields", "MyController")')"})
```

Your second parameter `false` is useless, since that technically should be of type `string` since it is for a `templateName` based on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor(v=vs.118).aspx).

Also as Chris Pratt and I were discussing, in MVC 5.1+ you have to pass your HTML attributes with `new { htmlAttributes = new {...} }`.

This should help in solving your issue.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyTypes, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "myId", onchange = "onMyTypeChange('" + Url.Action("GetMyFields", "MyController") + "')" } })
```

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thanks for the edit haha it is early, I don't why I had that line in there about prefixing the `@` haha completely forgot about the keyword discussion.. off to dunkin donuts I go

Comment: No problem. It took me 4 edits to get my edit right ;)